# C++ Project with well designed exception mechanism

Tags: c++, exception

Does anyone know a opensource c++ application with a well designed/robust exception mechanism so I can get some inspiration? Most code/examples I see do questionable things like:

1. Throw objects with a message string as argument. Seems wrong because it marks the exception as fatal, a error message wich can be displayed to the user higher up leaves little room for client code trying to handle the exception. Even if the exception is fatal, things like diffirent locales (languages) makes formatting a message at the point of throw seem like a bad idea to me.
2. Use tons of different exception classes derived from a base exception class. Just feels wrong introducing a new class/type for every single thing that can go wrong (open file, read file, write file, create thread, etc...). Catching all unhandled exceptions at the highest level using the base type loses type information required to display meaningfull error messages.
3. Use one exception class derived from a base exception class for every component/library and give it a error code as argument to indicate the exact error. Catching with base type results in ambiguity. (Whose error code "3" did we catch? )...

Some pointers in the right direction would be welcome.

Comment: The simplest C++ exception mechanism I've seen is Symbian's take on it. Everything is an int, no exception classes or messages. A 'Leave' is synonymous with an exception: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_TRAP

Comment: (1) Exception strings are for programmers, not users.  Don't use locales there.  (2) How else could the compiler determine the right place to unwind to? (3) Obviously that's the problem with error codes.  Don't do that.

Comment: @James: Simple is not always good.  In that case I'd call it bad.

Comment: (2 again) if you're handling exceptions using the base types, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Why so? It works very well. I'd consider a class hierarchy for exceptions completely overkill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To address all three of these, I found that the best for me is to throw my own custom exception that's derived from `std::runtime_error`.   Like this:

```
#include <exception>

class ChrisAException : public std::runtime_error
{
      /// constructor only which passes message to base class
      ChrisAException(std::string msg)
      : std::runtime_error(msg)
      {

      }
}
```

It allows accepting a string, which I always put in something like the following format (assuming `x` negative was not a valid input and meant something calling it was in error):

```
#include "ChrisAException.h"

void myfunction(int x)
{

    if(x < 0) 
    {
        throw ChrisAException("myfunction(): input was negative!");
    }

    // rest of your function
}
```

For this one, keep in mind that the strings in these exceptions are more for the programmer than the end user.  It's the programmer of the interface's job to display something meaningful in the locale when there's a failure.  The strings in the exception can either be logged or seen at debug time (preferable!)

This way you can ultimately catch it with:

```
try
{
      // high level code ultimately calling myfunction

}
catch(ChrisAException &cae)
{
       // then log cae.what()
}
catch(std::runtime_error &e)
{
       // this will also catch ChrisAException's if the above block wasn't there
}
catch(...)
{
      // caught something unknown
}
```

I personally don't like deriving too many types of exceptions, or giving an error code.  I let the string message do the reporting.

In general, I use C++ exceptions to mean "something went wrong with the program" and *not* to handle normal use cases.  Thus, for me, a thrown exception during the algorithm execution either means "flag the user that something went wrong" or "don't tell the user" (depending on how critical that code was to what they were doing) but certainly log it and let the programmers know somehow.

I don't use C++ exceptions to handle cases that aren't essentially programming errors, e.g., some kind of incorrect logic or something being called wrong.  For example, I wouldn't use C++ exceptions to handle normal program situations like an empty DVD not being in the drive for a DVD writing program.  For that, I'd have explicit return code that allows the user to know whether an empty DVD was there (maybe with a dialog etc.)

Keep in mind that part of C++ exception handling is to unwind the stack up to a `try-catch` block.  To me that means, abort what's going on in the program and clean up the stack.  In the case of something like my DVD example, you shouldn't really want to unwind much of the stack.  It wasn't catastrophic. You should simply let the user know and then let them try again.

But again, this is my preferred way of using C++ exceptions, based on experience and my reading.  I'm open to opinions otherwise.

edit: Changed `std::exception` to `std::runtime_error` based on commenter advice.

Comment: How does the highest level catching code determine the kind of exception so it can try to handle it, or print a error message for the user? Compare the what string ?

Comment: Edited the post to explain this.

Comment: `std::exception` does not have a constructor that takes a string, only in MSVC's (non-conforming) implementation. Not terribly important, but still. For compilers that follow the standard in this regard, you can probably use `std::runtime_error` instead.

Comment: You cannot handle `catch(...)`, so that block should _always_ end in `throw;` to continue unwinding.

Comment: @Mooing Duck, I disagree with that. For instance, if you are catching because you simply cannot let exceptions pass upward further in the stack (this happens in threading often). Or if you are catching because you're going to return an error code (for instance at the top level of an API). So I'm not really clear on what you mean by "you cannot handle it".

Comment: If you cannot "fix" the situation that caused the error, (which you cannot do because you don't even know the _type_ of error), then the program is left in an unknown state.  The only "correct" thing to do in that situation is to crash/reboot.  There's articles about this all over the internet.

Comment: That's an extreme viewpoint.  Please post such an article.  An better alternative to "crashing/rebooting" is to prevent the crash, land safely and then log or tell the programming team that something went wrong under this `try-catch` block.  Even if the information is vague it's better than a crash.

Comment: @MooingDuck: How is the program left in an unknown state if a `catch (...)` block is entered?  Unwinding took place, destructors ran, transactions were rolled back, memory was freed.  Something has gone wrong, but your invariants are protected.

Comment: The invariants may not have been protected in the object that threw the exception.  If I have a user_data object that threw and exception because it's internal structure became invalid somehow, it's not safe to save the user_data.  Or if the logging stream threw and exception, it's not safe to log anything.